# Json message validation on confluent kafka with schema registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am sending a json message to a kafka topic using spring boot kafka with java. The message has a json schema published on schema registry.

When the producer sends the message, how do I get the json message to be validated against its schema? I can see the json message appear on the topic and see the schema on the schema registry.

The producer config includes:

```
   @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, TestUser> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);

        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
              "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer");
        configProps.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
       
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, TestUser> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate(producerFactory());
    }
```

TestUser:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TestUser {
    @JsonProperty
    public String firstName;

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    public String lastName;
}
```

MsgSender:

```
public void sendMessage(TestUser user) {

        ProducerRecord<String, TestUser> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(fcsTopic,user.getFirstName(),user);
        final ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, TestUser>> resultListenableFuture =
                kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);

        resultListenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, TestUser>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, TestUser> result) {
                System.out.println("Sent message=[" + user +
                        "] with offset=[" + result.getRecordMetadata().offset() + "]");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to send message=["
                        + user + "] due to : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Schema Registry:

```
{
        "subject": "test.user.topic-value",
        "version": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "schemaType": "JSON",
        "schema": "{\"$schema\":\"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#\",\"title\":\"Test User\",\"type\":\"object\",\"additionalProperties\":false,\"properties\":{\"firstName\":{\"oneOf\":[{\"type\":\"null\",\"title\":\"Not included\"},{\"type\":\"string\"}]},\"lastName\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"required\":[\"lastName\"]}
 }
```

There are 2 validation configs available on the topic to apply validation to message:

confluent.key.schema.validation

confluent.value.schema.validation

1. I noticed when no validation is applied, I can send a message and consume a message with no issues. The consumer has the appropriate Deserializers.
2. When only key validation is enabled, confluent.key.schema.validation: true, when I send a message, I see an error in the broker log:

```
INFO Invalid record due to missing magic byte (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.validator.RecordSchemaValidator)
ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=1] Error processing append operation on partition dfm.fcs.csv.topic-0 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.InvalidRecordException: One or more records have been rejected
```

3. When only value validation is enabled, confluent.value.schema.validation:
   I noticed if one of the json message **required** fields has a **null** value, it does not fail validation.

**This value validation can be fixed and enabled by adding to Producer config:**

```
 configProps.put(KafkaJsonSchemaSerializerConfig.FAIL_INVALID_SCHEMA, "true");
```

Any other config to correctly enable json key and value message validation?

Thanks,
B.

Comment: With that serializer setting, your producer should fail if the value doesn't match the schema. Can you share your schema and code as a [mcve]?

Comment: Updated query with more code. @OneCricketeer

Comment: I've not used these topic schema validation settings. This is an Enterprise feature, so I suggest you contact Confluent Support